# match common rows between different dataframes in a new organized df

Tags: r, dataframe, matching, ranking

Can someone help me to match three or more different ranked df to have a final one containing only the rows common to all of them? I am trying match and merge functions but I can not go any further.

here is how the data may look like:

`A <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x=runif(10))
   B <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x=runif(10))
   C <- data.frame(letter=LETTERS[sample(10)], x=runif(10))`

"letter" is however the "row.names" on each df has only one column with the numerical "x", the ranked values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not many details, but I try to suggest a basic approach. The function below tests if the two arguments provided from `dataFrame1` and `dataFrame2` match between them. In the evenience of `TRUE` answer, it stores the common value in a new `dataFrame3`. The index in the square brackets represents the rows that you would like to test.

```
matching_row <- function(x, y) {
        if (identical(x, y)) {
        dataFrame3 <- x
        }
}
dataFrame3 <- matching_row(dataFrame$x[row], dataFrame2$x[row])
```

You can modify the function according to the characteristics of your data by adding, i.e., a `loop` if the dataframes are quite big, ore more strict/flexible logical conditions to test the identity between dataframes.